# Attempting to output a SQL developer export to Excel by running a batch file

Tags: sql, excel, batch-file

I'm new to running tasks through batch files. I have a batch and sql script that outputs to csv, which works. But I want the output to be in Excel. I've edited these scripts so that it can output in Excel. The proces does create an Excel file. However when I attempt to open the Excel file, I get an error that the file has not been found. What am I doing wrong?

This is the SQL script. Let's say this is stored in file.sql :

```
set verify off
set define off
set termout off
set heading off
set pages 50000
set feedback off
set newpage none
set trimspool on
set linesize 1000
set decimal 


whenever sqlerror exit


spool C:\pathname\filename.xlsx append

select
'' 
||COLUMN_1||
';'||COLUMN_2||
';'||COLUMN_3||
''
FROM blahblah.tablename;

spool off
exit
```

This is the batch script:

```
echo off

if exist C:\pathname\filename.xlsx del C:\pathname\filename.xlsx

:: creating a header

echo COLUMN_1;COLUMN_2;COLUMN_3;

sqlplus blahblah/password@databasename @C:\pathname\file.sql
```

I've basically just changed the .csv file extension in the scripts to a .xlsx extension but clearly this isn't enough, because I can't open the file.

Also, how do I just select all (select *) through this proces? I've tried changing that too, but I just ended up with no data at all (not even a csv file)

Comment: Why going the way over a batch-file, why not importing the data into Excel directly?

Comment: @aschipfl I need a regular (let's say weekly) update of this file, which I'm going to use as input in another application that's also set to run every week or so.... Basically, I need an automatic update, so that I can run this other application. I plan to use a task scheduler to run this batch file very week orso

Answer (score 0):

In Excel VBA:

```
 Sub ImportData()
 Dim Conn as New Connection
 Conn.Connectionstring = ' get details from here https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/   depending on version of sql you are using
 conn.open
 dim rs as new recordset
 rs.open "Select * from BlahBlahTablename",conn
 if not rs.eof then ' if we have data
     range("a2").copyfromrecordset rs
 end if
 Dim f as field
 dim r as range
 for each f in rs.fields
   r = f.name
   set r = r.offset(0,1)
  next f
 rs.close
 set rs = nothing
 conn.close
 End Sub
```

This assumes a reference to ado in excel

Comment: thanks, is there no way to adapt either the sql file or the batch file? Idon't know VBA that well either.

Comment: You could adapt it so it ran in VBScript by declaring an excel object - you'd have to use late binding. It's possible that there's something in SQL Server now about exporting to excel - I haven't used it since 2007 so I'm rather rusty.